# how to fix multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm setting up multiple foreign keys but it shows error

```
  from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy     
  sql= SQLAlchemy(app)
  app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
  app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:///test'
  app.config['SECERET_KEY'] = 'RANDAM'

  class Users(sql.Model):

    __tablename__='users'

    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, 
                                                    default='')
    name = sql.Column(sql.String(25),nullable=False, default='')
    username = sql.Column(sql.String(25),nullable=False, default='')
    email = sql.Column(sql.String(25), primary_key=True,nullable=False, 
                                                    default='')
    password = sql.Column(sql.String(100),nullable=False, default='')
    reg_time = sql.func.current_timestamp()
    online =  sql.Column(sql.String(1),nullable=False, default='')

 class friendgroup(sql.Model):

    __tablename__='friendgroup'

    group_id = sql.Column(sql.Integer,sql.ForeignKey('users.id'),
            primary_key=True,nullable=False, default='')
    fg_name = sql.Column(sql.String(25), primary_key=True, nullable=False, 
                                                  default='')
    owner_email = sql.Column(sql.String(25),sql.ForeignKey('users.email'), 
             primary_key=True, nullable=False,default='')
    description = sql.Column(sql.String(25), nullable=False, default='')

 class belong(sql.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'belong'

    group_id=sql.Column(sql.Integer,sql.ForeignKey('friendgroup.group_id')
                     ,primary_key=True,nullable=False,default='')
    email = sql.Column(sql.String(25),sql.ForeignKey('users.email'),
               nullable=False, default='', primary_key=True)
    owner_email = sql.Column(sql.String(25),  
           sql.ForeignKey('friendgroup.owner_email'),nullable=False, 
                                       default='', primary_key=True)
    fg_name = sql.Column(sql.String(25), 
        sql.ForeignKey('friendgroup.fg_name'),nullable=False, default='', 
                                         primary_key=True)

 sql.create_all()
 app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect all these will be entered into the database but it shows error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
>   (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1005, 'Can\'t create table
>   `test`.`friendgroup` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")')

Answer (score 0):

When I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, it shows this error under the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section:

> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced
>   columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and
>   the referenced table do not match for constraint. Note that the
>   internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with
>   `>= InnoDB-4.1.12`, and such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

We can disregard the stuff about `ENUM` and `SET`, and the type definitions between the two are exact, so that just leaves the issue about the index.

If you add `index=True` to the column definitions of `Users.email` and `friendgroup.fg_name` it provides an index that can be used for mysql to generate the foreign keys on and your tables should create.

However, I would advise a rethink of your primary keys your tables. You are defining each of those tables with an autoincrement primary key field, yet include other fields in a composite primary key. You don't need to do that. If you remove the non-autoincrement columns from the primary key and add a unique constraint on them instead, all your problems go away.

Additionally, by including the field `friendgroup.owner_email` in either the primary key or a unique constraint means that each user can only own a single friend group. Is that what you want? Similarly, having `owner_email` and `fg_name` in the primary key of the `belong` table would mean that only one user can belong to any group owned by a particular user.

If it helps, this is how I would put those models together. It resolves your issues with the foreign keys and uses relationship attributes instead of duplicating data like email addresses and group names across tables.

```py
class Users(sql.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sql.Column(sql.String(25), nullable=False)
    username = sql.Column(sql.String(25), nullable=False)
    email = sql.Column(sql.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = sql.Column(sql.String(100), nullable=False)
    reg_time = sql.Column(
        sql.TIMESTAMP, server_default=sql.func.current_timestamp()
    )
    online = sql.Column(sql.String(1), nullable=False, default="")


class friendgroup(sql.Model):

    __tablename__ = "friendgroup"

    group_id = sql.Column(
        sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True
    )
    fg_name = sql.Column(sql.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    owner_id = sql.Column(
        sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False
    )
    description = sql.Column(sql.String(25), nullable=False, default="")
    owner = sql.relationship("User")


class belong(sql.Model):

    __tablename__ = "belong"

    group_id = sql.Column(
        sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey("friendgroup.group_id"), primary_key=True
    )
    user_id = sql.Column(
        sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True
    )

    user = sql.relationship("User")
    group = sql.relationship("friendgroup")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but one thing I wanna ask that if I remove connectivity from email address and owner email from table friendgroup and  belong so how can I see list of users present into a particular group because friendgroup is the source for groups and in belong, users are present particularly according to group and with the help of primary and foreign keys it cannot be duplicate

Comment: That's what the relationship attributes allow you to do, you can access the email of a friendgroup owner through `friendgroup.owner.email`. Similarly, because each `belong` instance has a group_id, you can always set up a relationship to return you each groups users. You need to familiarise yourself with https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship